# AsyncStorage.getItem in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to create a simple to-do application to practice React-Native and I'm having trouble retrieving the items when the `componentDidMount`

The app `state` :

```
this.state = {
  task: "",
  tasks: []
};
```

When the user adds a new task `handleAddTask` runs and I attached the `AsyncStorage.setItem` as a callback for `setState` so that the tasks array is saved to the storage after the state is updated.

```
handleAddTask = () => {

  let notEmpty = this.state.task.trim().length > 0;
  if (notEmpty) {
    this.setState(
      prevState => {
        return {
          tasks: prevState.tasks.concat(prevState.task)
        };
      },() => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(this.state.tasks));
      }
    );
  }

};
```

Similarly, when the user taps on a list item `handleDelete` runs, it removes the selected task from the tasks array and updates the `AsyncStorage`

```
handleDelete = index => {

  this.setState(
    prevState => {
      return {
        tasks: prevState.tasks.filter((place, i) => {
          return i !== index;
        })
      };
    },() => {
      AsyncStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(this.state.tasks));
    }
  );

};
```

However, I'm trying to retreive the tasks array from `AsyncStorage` inside `componentDidMount` like so :

```
componentDidMount() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem("tasks")
    .then(value => {
      this.setState({ "tasks": value });
    })
    .done();
}
```

The way I'm displaying the tasks list is by passing the state through a component called `List`:

```
<List
  listItems={this.state.tasks}
  handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
/>
```

Inside `List.js` I'm mapping through the tasks array:

```
export default class List extends Component {

  render() {

    const namesOutput = this.props.listItems.map((name, i) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={i}
        onPress={() => this.props.handleDelete(i)}
        activeOpacity={0.6}
        style={styles.listItemContainer}
      >
        <Text style={styles.listItemText}>{name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ));

    return (
      <View style={styles.listContainer}>
        <ScrollView>{namesOutput}</ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

And I get the following error:

**TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.props.listItem.map')**

I've been commenting lines here and there to see where the problems is and I can only assume that it's in the way I'm getting the items in `componentDidMount`

Is there something about asynchronous JavaScript that I missed? 
Also, do I have to `JSON.parse` when I do `getItem` ? 
If anyone has additional feedback about my code in general I'd love to learn more.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saved to storage `JSON.stringify()` values, then used it without using `JSON.parse()`. I think that this is the problem. You can check it by stop on break point on your `List` component render before it maps its props, and detect that your `props.listItems` isn't array after `componentDidMount`.

Comment: I tried using `JSON.parse(value)` while setting the tasks state but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: I solved the problem by checking the returned `value` from the `then()` promise and only setting the state when `value` is not `null`

Comment: If you saved corrupted values, nothing will help you to parse them. If you will save good values with `JSON.strigify()` you cant do nothing then `JSON.parse()` them when you will fetch them back. So for your null values, you should first check, why do you have null values at all?

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage` returns a promise. Therefore when you call to retrieve items in `componentDidMount`, the code will run passed the `.then` even before the values are retrieved.

My suggestion is that you give listItem some dummy objects so that it is not undefined the first it is called.

Second suggestion would be use `await` instead of `.then` and use a helper function when calling listenItem.map so that it's not called until values have been loaded.